# Power Query Merge two columns with distinct values

Tags: excel

i have two columns coming from different tables. both are for Invoice Date, i want to merge these two columns to a new column with distinct date, Example

```
Column1 Column 2 Custom Column (new)
Invoice_Date Invoice Date  New Date
19/04/2021   19/04/2021    19/04/2021
27/01/2021   null          27/01/2021
17/11/2020   17/11/2020    17/11/2020
```

thanks
aleem

Answer (score 0):

i have used the conditional column form the Add Column tab, and use the if  then option.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question or a statement of what you have done?  If an answer, please include the coud you have used. You'll be able to accept it in a few days.  If it is a statement of what you have done, you should delete this (since it is not an answer) and edit your original question to include the actual code you have used, as well as the results from trying this.